# Python: Script won't find word in text file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to find specific words from a text file, however my script doesn't seem to be able to match the word to what's written on a line in the text file, even though I know it matches. I've noticed there are spaces but since I am saying `entry in line`, shouldn't it work?

I have also tried:

```
  if str(entry) in line:, 
  if str(entry) in str(line): and 
  if entry in str(line):
```

but none of them seem to work either

I can't see where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
with open(address+'file_containing_data_I_want.txt') as f:
    for entry in System_data:
        print "Entry:"
        print entry 
        for line in f:
            print "Start of line"
            print line
            print"End of line"
            if entry in line:
                print "Found entry in line" #This never gets printed
```

Using the print statements (for just the first entry) I see:

```
Entry:
Manufacturer


Start of line
??

End of line
Start of line


End of line
Start of line
Manufacturer=manufacturer_data

End of line
Start of line
Model=model_data

End of line
Start of line


End of line
Start of line


End of line
```

The text file looks like this (Note:I can't change the text file as this is the way I will be receiving it, `'` indicates a blank line):

```
'
'
Manufacturer=manufacturer_data
Model=model_data
'
'
'
```

**UPDATE:**
Changing my script to:

```
with open(address+'file_containing_data_I_want.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print "Start of line %s" % line
        print"End of line" 
        for entry in System_data:
            print "Entry: %s" % entry
            if entry in line.strip():
                print "Found entry in line"
```

Results in this being printed (Still no "Found entry in line"):

```
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: 
End of line
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: Manufacturer=manufacturer_data
End of line
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: Model=model_data
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: 
End of line
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: 
End of line
```

Changing my code to this:

```
for line in f:
    print "Start of line: %s" % line.strip("\r\n")
    print "End of line" 
    for entry in System_data:
        print "Entry: %s" % entry.strip()
        if entry.strip() in line.strip("\r\n"):
            print "FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

Gives me this:

```
Start of line: ??
End of line
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: 
End of line
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: Manufacturer=manufacturer_data
End of line
Entry: Manufacturer
Entry: Model
Start of line: Model=model_data
End of line
```

Comment: It seems like your `entry` has newline in it. Try to strip it in your `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems the issue was that the string was actually in hexadecimal form.
But it only appeared in hexadecimal form to me when I used `print repr(line)` it appeared like:
`'\x00m\x00a\x00n\x00u\x00f\x00a\x00c\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00r\x00_\x00d\x00a\x0‌​0t\x00a\x00'`

So I changed my code to the following:

```
with open(address+'file_containing_data_I_want.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for entry in System_data:
            line=line.strip()
            line = re.sub(r'[^\w=]', '', line)
            if entry in line:
                print "Found entry in line"
```

This script now enters the loop `if entry in line:` and prints `"Found entry in line"`

Answer (score 1):

You read to the end of the file the after the first loop. Swap the loops instead, so each `entry` in `System_data` gets checked at each line of the file:

```
for line in f:
    print "Start of line %s" % line
    print "End of line" 
    for entry in System_data:
        print "Entry: %s" % entry
        if entry.strip() in line.strip("\r\n"):
            print "Found entry in line" #This now gets printed
```

or you can correct this behavior in your current code by calling `f.seek(0)` before `for line in f`

Comment: I changed my code to be similar to yours (except I also added the line.strip() ), neither this method or your method seems to be working for me, It is still not finding the entry in the line

Comment: Try adding `f.seek(0)`  to your original code as shown in my update

Comment: I have, it is still not entering the loop to print "Found entry in line" for some reason

Comment: I have updated my question, it is still not registering that the entry is in the line. I also tried `if  "Manufacturer" in line.strip("\r\n"):` and that also didn't entering the loop to print "FOUND!!!"

Comment: I noticed something strange, when I use the print statement: `print line + "<=End"` it prints `"<=Endacturer=manufacturer_data"` Do you have any ides what is going on?

Comment: try `print repr(line)`, what does it print?

Comment: That prints 
`'\x00m\x00a\x00n\x00u\x00f\x00a\x00c\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00r\x00_\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00'<=End`

Answer (score 0):

You should strip all blanks/newlines from both the entry and lines in file. So, prefix everything with

```
entry = entry.strip()
```

and change the

```
if entry in line:
```

to

```
if entry in line.strip():
```

EDIT:
also, what Moses Koledoye says